# Highcharts padding between plot and graph, how to remove?

Tags: highcharts

How can i remove padding between my chart and plot. I want my chart to start from the edge of plot and end the same way, but no matter what I try, i cannot remove padding :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that with:

```
    plotOptions: {
    series: {
        pointPadding: 0,
        groupPadding: 0,      
        }
    },
```

See working example at jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d9854qLm/.

Hope that is what you want.

Comment: fiddle is not running, pls check it

Comment: I searched for a long time focused on calling it margin. Try this for the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bickerstoff/GBp9V/634/