# Highcharts add padding between (dynamic) line charts and graph

Tags: highcharts

I have a line chart which is being dynamically updated. I want to add space between the right most plotted point and the borders of the plot[image]

I have tried solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991486/highcharts-remove-space-between-plot-border-and-actual-chart?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787376/highcharts-padding-between-plot-and-graph-how-to-remove) but they do not work. Under the [plotOptions API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point) doesn't seem to be the relevant information.

Comment: No, **plotOptions** won't have anything related to this. Look at the **xAxis** properties: *min* and *max*, *minPadding* and *maxPadding*, *startOnTick* and *endOnTick*  - http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis

Comment: You can also add null points and set the [ordinal](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal) parameter as false.